# TestNG Dataprovider not supported in Maven surefire?

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have following TestNG Unit Test class:

```
public class SomeTest extends AbstractEntityTest {
    ...
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getClasses() throws Exception {
        return this.getClassesForPackage(pack);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "getClasses")
    public void testEntity(final Class<?> entityClass) throws Exception {
        //test class...
    }
}
```

This test is nicely executed when running in eclipse but Maven seems to ignore it completely. To determine the problem I have added another dummy test method to this test class and that one is executed by Maven. It seems that the surefire plugin does not recognize the method testEntity as a test method because of either the dataProvider in the annotation or the parameter in the method?

Maven version: 3.0.3
Surefire plugin version: 2.13
TestNG version: 6.8

**UPDATE**
I do not use a testng.xml file to define which tests to run. This should also not be necessary according to [this explanation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html):

> This is the only step that is required to get started - you can now create tests in your test source directory (eg, src/test/java. As long as they are named using the defaults such as *Test.java they will be run by Surefire as TestNG tests.

Comment: It doesnt look like the case.  I did a quick check - added the following case to a suite and ran mvn test and it worked well..
@DataProvider
public Object[][] getClasses() throws Exception {
       return new Object[][]{{String.class}};
   }
@Test(dataProvider = "getClasses")
public void testEntity(final Class<?> entityClass) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("In class"+ entityClass.getCanonicalName());
}

Comment: To a suite? You mean you added it to an existing test class or do you use XML suite files to configure the tests to run?

Comment: Are you including groups in your pom.xml? If you are, then the method above will not be included (because it doesn't belong to one). If not, run with verbose="10" in your testng.xml and see if you can find anything suspicious.

Comment: I just specified what I was doing since it wasn't really clear as to how you were running it.  The edit does explain it now.  I have taken out the suitexmlfile out of the pom as well and the *Test.java files do run and the dataprovider test runs as well.  The only thing that I saw as a diff between ur config n mine was i am on maven 2.2.1.  Not sure whether that should make a diff..Probably you can share your surefire plugin config..

Comment: I have not set a specific sureplugin in my POM so we use default settings. According to the link in my question this is not required?